# Error with latexalpha2 package

Tags: errors, luatex, packages, latexalpha2

This is a simple MWE including `latexalpha2` package. I have Wolfram Engine installed on my PC and added the WolframScript into the path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexalpha2}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[  \wolfram{Solve[x+1==0,x]} \]
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

> Package latexalpha2 Error: WolframScript cannot be found, which is required to use latexalpha2. \begin{document}

---

#### EDIT

The output is produced correctly but the error remains.
[image]

---

#### EDIT 2

I tried to produce a 3D plot which took a while to be compile. During complilation I got the following messages before the error shows up

> 'command' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: did you call pdflatex with `--shell-escape`?

Comment: Yes. The command is `pdflatex.exe -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --enable-write18 %.tex`

Comment: You don`t need both `--shell-escape` and `--enable-write18`. That is the same option. Can you run `wolframscript` on a command line?

Comment: the package uses `\immediate\write18{command -v wolframscript; echo $? > latexalpha2_check.tmp}%` to check that the command works, but I'm not sure if the `echo $?` syntax does anything useful if you are not using a unix style shell?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer WolframScript is fully functionable on a command line.

Comment: All the shell escape calls are assuming a bash style shell, so `command`, `rm` etc if you are using windows cmd shell you probably need to make some edits to the syntax in the write18 calls

Comment: @David Carlisle How can I do that?Do I need to edit the package?

Comment: yes take a copy of the the package  and change the unix shell calls by whatever you would use on the windows commandline, I don't have wolframscript or a windows tex, so I can't help further sorry

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I hope you could take a look at my follow-up question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/578144/2288.

Answer (score 1):

This result can be obtained
[image: c]

running this code (tested with windows, `pdflatex` and `lualatex`)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\RequirePackage{float}% 
\RequirePackage{booktabs}%

\RequirePackage[nocache]{latexalpha2wlua} % option cache (faster the second run) or nocache (recalculate always)

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \wolframgraphics{Plot3D[Sin[x]Cos[y],{x,-2Pi,2Pi},{y,-2Pi,2Pi}]}{Plot3Db}
    \includegraphics{Plot3Db.pdf}
    \caption{Plot 3D of $f(x,y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)$}
    \centering
\end{figure}

Laplace Transform of $t^4 sin(t)$

$$ \wolfram{LaplaceTransform[t^4 Sin[t],t,s]} $$

Generates a power series expansion

$$ \wolfram{Series[Exp[x],{x,0,5}]} $$

\bigskip    

Compton scattering for electron \bigskip

$\wolframalpha{Compton scattering for electron}$

\bigskip    

Solve the equation  $a x^2+b x+c=0$ and display the corresponding results

\wolframsolve{a x^2+b x+c==0}{x}

\newpage
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
    \wolframtable{Join[{{x,x^2,x^3}}, Table[{i,i^2,i^3},{i,5}]]}
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Generate a table of $x$, $x^2$, $x^2$}
\end{table} 

\bigskip

The population of Shanghai is $\wolframalpha{Shanghai population}$, which
is $\wolframalpha{ratio of Shanghai population and NYC population}$ times the
population of New York City.

\bigskip

Solve differential equations $y'(x) + y(x) = a *sin(x)*y(x)*x $

\wolframdsolve{y'[x]+y[x]==a Sin[x]}{y[x]}{x}

\end{document}
```

The code for the package `latexalpha2wlua` and some comments can be found in

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579254/161015